# Simple RewriteRule do not work at php/apache in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I do not know why, but this simple Rule will not work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^rubbellos\.png/$ rubbellos/rubbelbild_png.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^rubbellos\.css/$ rubbellos/rubbellos_css.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

If I copy the xyz/rubbellos/rubbelbild_png.php to browser it is OK.

My approach is to bring the request of rubbellos.png to the .php-file. But I get a file not found.

Thx for any hint in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

- use a `RewriteBase` since you're talking about a subdirectory `/xyz/` in your question.
- disable `MultiViews` option to avoid unexpected behaviour with `rubbellos` (virtual file and existing directory).

You can replace your current code by this one in your htaccess (which has to be in `/xyz/` folder)

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xyz/

RewriteRule ^rubbellos\.png$ rubbellos/rubbelbild_png.php [L]
RewriteRule ^rubbellos\.css$ rubbellos/rubbellos_css.php [L]
```

Note: don't forget to replace `xyz` by your real subdirectory's name

Comment: thx. I changed it to the code above. RewriteBase is in my case root.